# Equivalent sets for naturals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Prove that the sets $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ are equivalent.

My friend gave me the following proof:

Proof.

It suffices to show that $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality so we need to find a function. In particular, we need

$$\{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}\} \longleftrightarrow \{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}$$

Consider $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Define $\phi(f) = (1 ... 1 0 1 ... 1 0 ...) = ((1 ... 1) 0 (1 ... 1) 0 ...)$, where the $i$th grouping of $1$s can be treated as $f(i)$.

We have $\phi:\{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$, with $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ having the same cardinality as $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$.

Then we also have $\phi(f) = 1_{\{(n, f(n)) | n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$.

End.

He barely explained this and did not explain any further. I have been trying to make sense of it but cannot figure out what is happening or how to formalize it. Can somebody write it down as a clear, formal proof and/or explain it? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Your friend is a conflating terminology abusing concepts at an alarming rate. "so we need to find a function" Um... a function that does what?  $f(x)=\sin x$ is a function, will that do? "In particularly we need $\{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}\} \longleftrightarrow \{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}$" Um... what dos that *mean*.  I can't tell if you friend has no idea what s/he is talking about or if s/he as the correct basic idea by explaining *terribly*. I'm not really motivated to find out which.

Comment: @fleablood Exactly, which is what I was hoping could be resolved here. The friend is pretty good at analysis but he often fails to explain ideas well. I am sure it is the latter, which still isn't good.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if your friend is a CS major or likes computability theory, because I feel the idea resembles how you would pass multiple integer parameters to a Turing machine.

First, use Schröder–Bernstein. Changing the codomain from $\{0,1\}$ to $\mathbb N$ gives an injection from $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ to $\def\N{\mathbb N}\N^{\N}$, so it suffices to find another injection the other way around, i.e. from $\def\N{\mathbb N}\N^{\N}$ to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.

Now this is how you would do it: given $f:\N\rightarrow\N$, think of the output as an infinitely (on one side) long tape, where any entry has either 0 or 1 written on it. How would you code an integer sequence $\{f(n)\}_n$ onto it? Well, start by writing $f(0)+1$ 1's, then write a 0 as a separator, and then write $f(1)+1$ 1's, etc. It is clear that this gives an injection (it "codes" an infinite tuple).

EDIT: More explicit expressions are given here. For changing the codomain, you could view it as post-composing the function by the inclusion map $i:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\N$. Since $i$ is injective (i.e. a monomorphism), given any two maps $f,g, i\circ f=i\circ g$ implies $f=g$. Hence $f\mapsto i\circ f$ gives an injection.

For the converse side, given $f:\N\rightarrow\N$, define $g_f:\N\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ (associated with $f$) given by $g_f(x)=0$ when $x=2n+1+\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)$ for some $n\in\N$ and $g_f(x)=0$ otherwise. Check that $g_f$ agrees with the above description, and $f\mapsto g_f$ is an injection.

Comment: So we need to injections per the theorem, understood. How does changing the codomain give such an injection? As for the two functions, how would one define these respective injective functions? Also, he is an applied math major.

Comment: @Kraftsman I have updated the answer to be a bit more explicit. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}= \{$ countable sequences of $0$s and $1$s.$\}$.

$\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}= \{$ countable sequences of natural numbers$\}$.

Let $s\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} = \{a_i\} = \{a_1, a_2, a_3.....\}$.

We can map $s\to s' \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ by replacing every $a_i$  with a string of $a_i$ $1$s followed be a zero.

It's a simple concept. If the sequence $s= \{3,1,5,0, 7, 2,.... \}$ then $s'$ would be $s' = \{\underbrace{1,1,1}_3,0,\underbrace{1}_1,0,\underbrace{1,1,1,1,1}_5,0,\underbrace{}_00,\underbrace{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}_7,0, \underbrace{1,1}_2,0,.....\}$

Defining this formally and recursively can by done but.... we can see what is happening and doing it formally will be tedious.

Your friend actually did this in the opposite direction.  He took something like $t \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ as mapped something like $t = \{0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,....\}= \{\underbrace{0}_0,\underbrace{1,1,1,0}_3,\underbrace{0}_0,\underbrace{1,0}_1,\underbrace{1,1,0}_2,\underbrace{0}_0,....\}\to \{0,3,0,1,2,0,....\}=t'\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$

That function migh actually be easier to define formally but I thought it wasn't as easy to describe.

....

Anyhooo.... we can prove this is bijective by... saying "Aw, come on, isn't it obvious... any sequence of ones and zeros can be 'blocked' as a set of ones separated by a zero so that string and the following zero is mapped to be then natural number that is number of ones, and we can do that for each block, so it's gotta be surjective.  And if a string *has* a specific number of ones it can only be mapped *from* that number.  So it's gotta be injective."

That the proves their cardinalities are equal.

....

I must confess I found the wording confusing.  I that he was view $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ by their alternative and equivalent definition of $A^B = \{$functions $B\to A\}$.

This is equivalent ans $s\in A^{\mathbb N}$ where $s= \{a_1, a_2, a_3, ....\}$ is equivaly to a function $\sigma:\mathbb N \to A$ via $\sigma(n) = a_n$.

I got very confused reading his work.

Comment: And the "opposite direction" doesn't totally define a function...

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would one determine whether my friend's opposite direction "function" is bijective? Would it be analogous to yours?